# How do you know where you YAML file is breaking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I want my YAML parser in my Rails app to tell me where it trips up.

Often, after adding a lot of content to a YAML file I get this error in my rails app:

```
  Can not load translation from /path/to/rails/app/config/locales/en.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not
```

I want to know how I can debug this error so that it might tell me a line as to where I am failing. Right now my strategy consists of looking at the file and trying to find the mistake.

The trace through the application is no more descriptive and only tells me that the YAML parser was running.

Is it possible for the parser to tell where it is choking?

(I'm new to this so I am going to post a sample of what my YAML file looks like)

---

```
sp:
  static_pages:
            ship_agency_title: Agenciamiento de Barco
        ship_agency_summary: |
                        Mardom ofrece servicios de agenciamiento a diferentes líneas marítimas, entre las cuales están líneas con servicios especializados en el transporte de carga contenerizada.
        project_cargo_handling_title: Manejo de Proyectos
        project_cargo_hangling_description: |
                                            Mardom ofrece  un servicio especializado en el manejo de cargas con sobre-dimensión y/o sobrepeso (carga de proyectos).
        ship_and_cargo_brokerage_title: Fletamento de Buques y Carga
        ship_and_cargo_brokerage_description: |
                                              Marítima Dominicana S.A.S. cuenta con un equipo especializado en el servicio de fletamento de buques.
        storage_and_warehousing_title: Almacenaje
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try out a few online validators. Here's one:

http://yamllint.com/

Here's a previous question on how to validate yaml:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287346/yaml-validation